# disable screensaver from login screen

Tags: greeter

My os is Ele OS 5.1 Hera.

I have disabled screensaver from system settings and it is working.

But when OS wakesup from suspend or reboot, It comes to login screen waiting for my password. After few minutes (5 or 15 minutes;I do not know), OS goes to suspend.

Is it possible to disable screensaver from the login screen and if yes how?

Comment: You mention the screen saver but then say the "OS goes to suspend". I suspect this is not related to screen saver but to power management settings. Under "Power" System Settings there is a "Suspend when inactive for" setting may help you.

Comment: Hi endorama, Power settings -> both "Turn off display when  inactive for" and "suspend when inactive for" are set to never.